# Adding two different times (Nothing showing when i print this python code)

Tags: python-3.x

```
from datetime import time

def two_time(H,M):
    try:    
        att3 = datetime.datetime.strptime()
        att1 = att3.datetime.strptime('09:00','%H:%M %p')
        att2 = att3.datetime.strptime('11:00','%H:%M %p')
        time_zero = att3.datetime.strptime('00:00','%H:%M %p')
        print((att1 - time_zero + att2).time())
        return att3
    except:
        return 0
```

Comment: The blanket try/except is just hiding your errors. `strptime` takes 2 arguments so the first line would fail

Comment: You don't import `datetime` (just `datetime.time`), so the interpreter does not even know that `strptime` takes two arguments

Comment: a general note: please check [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - pure code "questions" lack context information... what do you actually want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your 5th line of code looks suspect:

```
att3 = datetime.datetime.strptime()
```

strptime() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)

Comment: - Sorry, just saw that Shelvinton pointed out the same thing in comments

Comment: this "answer" should also be a comment ;-)

Comment: Yeah, but I am 'shiny' brand new... I don't have the reputation to post comments directly. Nice work on your answer, seems a pretty solid guess as to what they are really trying to do.

Comment: Right, but should not take you too long to get the needed rep. Concerning the answer, the point is, it's a guess as you say, given only the code. Not ideal.