# AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'

Tags: python-3.x

```
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta

att1 = datetime.strptime('09:00 AM','%H:%M %p')

att2 = datetime.timedelta(minutes = 15)

time_zero = datetime.strptime('00:00 AM','%H:%M %p')

att3 =  (att1 - time_zero + att2).strftime("%X %p")

print(" sTime and Approx time is",att3)
```

If I removed datetime from att2, it is effected to the att3 
    att3 =  (att1 - time_zero + att2).strftime("%X %p")
AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "addtwotimes.py", line 5, in
>
> ```
> att2 = datetime.datetime(minutes = 15)
> ```
>
> AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute
>   'timedelta'

Comment: Well you imported timedelta you can use it just as `timedelta`. You use `datetime.timedelta` when you do `import datetime`

Comment: Change `att2 = datetime.timedelta(minutes = '15')` to `att2 = timedelta(minutes = '15')` as you already imported timedelta as `from datetime import timedelta`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906402/type-object-datetime-datetime-has-no-attribute-datetime)

Comment: @RahulRaut: it has to be `att2 = timedelta(minutes=15)` (int, not string). The OP already corrected the type though.

Comment: Also, `att3 = (att1 - time_zero + att2).strftime("%X %p")` wont work since a timedelta has no method `strftime()`. Formatting timedeltas is a bit more difficult, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538666/format-timedelta-to-string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding two different times (Nothing showing when i print this python code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58128110/adding-two-different-times-nothing-showing-when-i-print-this-python-code)

Comment: Also, att3 = (att1 - time_zero + att2).strftime("%X %p") wont work since a timedelta has no method strftime()